# Can anyone make a protobuf3 schema of the given content

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am new to protocol buffer.I want to see how the protobuff schema would be made for the given schem below.
    Person
    {
        "name": "RandomName",
        "lastname": "RandomLastName",
        "age": 44,
        "timedata1": [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4],
        "timedata2": [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4],
        "timedata3": [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4],
    }

I have tries making a schema on my own. Can anyone verify is this correct.

```
syntax="proto3";

package demo;

message Person{
    string fname=1;
    string lname=2;
    int32 age=3;


    message Timedata{

        message TimeValue{
            float timevalue=1;
        }

        repeated TimeValue timevalues=1;
    }
    repeated Timedata timedatas=4;
}

message People{
    repeated Person people=1;
}
```

Comment: why not use protobuf compiler to generate a schema for you and compare your result to it

Comment: But don't I have to make a .proto file before compiling. How shall I structure the message?

Comment: look at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto